# How to find similarity between IDs string and filenames?

Tags: php

I have a list of IDs

```
$Ids="1201,1240,1511,1631,1663,1666,1716,2067,2095";
```

and in the `/imgs/` folder there are many jpg filenames related to these IDs. But there are a lot of IDs that do not have any image.

for example there are in the /imgs/

```
1201_73.jpg
1201_2897.jpg
1240-9834.jpg
1240-24.jpg
1511-dsc984.jpg
1511-dsc34.jpg
```

What I want to achieve is to find which of the IDs **have** images in the img folder.

Thank you

Updated

$array = array();

```
  $foo = explode('.jpg', $images); 
  foreach($foo as $id) { 
    $digi = substr(trim($id), 0,4); 
    if(!in_array($digi, $array)) {
        array_push($array, $digi);
        echo $id . ".jpg <br/>";
          $where .= "id='$digi' or ";

    }
  }
```

Comment: _"I have a list of IDs"_ In a string? An array? Post the code you've tried please.

Comment: @jo8691 i have them in a string like the above with commas

Answer (score 0):

First, turn your string of IDs into an array.

```
$idsArray = explode(',', $Ids);
```

Now iterate through the directory, checking each file to see if it starts with the ID.

```
$hasImages = array();

foreach (new DirectoryIterator(__DIR__ . '/imgs') as $fileInfo) {
    if ($fileInfo->isDot() || $fileInfo->isDir()) {
        continue;
    }

    foreach ($idsArray as $id) {
        if (0 === strpos($fileInfo->getBasename(), $id)) {
            $hasImages[] = $id;
            break;
        }
    }
}

$hasImages = array_unique($hasImages);
```

`$hasImages` will contain an array of IDs which have an image.

Comment: Thank you for this. Please tell me, how can I echo the first found filename image that is associated with each ID ? I have updated my code to include a block I wrote that gets only the first found filename but it is from all filenames. The aim is to have the filenames that have an ID from the `$Ids`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$files = glob('/imgPath/*.jpg');
$hasImage = array_unique(array_map(function($file) {
            return explode('-', $file)[0];
        }, $files));

$withimages= array_diff(explode($Ids), $hasImage);
```